# Populating multiple fields with a pre "find" middleware

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to specify the fields that should always be populated for the user document in a pre "find" middleware, like this:

```
userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
 this.populate("followers following"); next(); 
});
```

Here is the user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "You must provide your first name."],
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "You must provide your last name."],
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "You must provide an email."],
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "You must provide a password."],
    },
    isVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    verificationToken: {
      type: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["user", "admin"],
      default: "user",
    },
    followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

But when I send the request it's just stuck not sending any response.

It works just fine when I only populate one field, either 'followers' or 'following', but together it won't work.
I tried a bunch of different ways, but nothing seems to work.

If anyone can help I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

**#1** Have you tried to seperate them ?

```
userSchema.pre('find', function (next) { 
  this.populate("followers").populate("following");
  next();
});
```

**#2** Or with an array of paths

```
userSchema.pre('find', function (next) { 
  this.populate(['followers', 'following']);
  next();
});
```

As documentation states [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document) and [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths):

```
The Document#populate() method does not support chaining. You need to 
call populate() multiple times, or with an array of paths, to populate 
multiple paths.
```

---

**#3** Or to use `deep-populate` if you're populating across multiple levels as documented [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate):

Comment: I've already tried chaining the populate method (Solution #1) and passing in the array of paths (Solution #2) and the third solution is of no help for this purpose. It's super weird that this doesn't work with one of these solutions.

Comment: Can you add more code to the question ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response...
It works completely fine when I just do:
this.populate("followers") or this.populate("following"), which means that both of the relationships work fine, so I doubt that the issue is somewhere else in my code...

Comment: Try `this.populate({ path: 'user', select: ['followers','following'] })`

Comment: I get an error - cannot populate path 'user' because it is not in your schema. I posted this issue on mongoose github repo and no one answered still. It's like it is not possible to do, but that would be crazy...

Comment: I wrote ‘user’ because i don’t know your model name, you should remove it and put your model name instead.

Comment: My model name is 'User'.
I tried both 'user' and 'User'...
Same error.

Comment: Can you share the schema code ?

Comment: I added the schema code in the question :)

Comment: Just to update, when I populate during the query, like:  
await UserModel.find({}).populate("followers following");  
This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the working solution.

The issue is that if the `populate()` method in the middleware has more than one field, it calls the middleware for each field and it triggers infinite recursion, which makes the request hanging.

The workaround is a bit weird, but pretty straight forward. We have to add the `_recursed` option so the middleware knows to avoid populating recursively.

```
userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
   if (this.options._recursed) {
     return next();
   }
   this.populate({ path: "followers following", options: { _recursed: true } });
   next();
});
```